# Java Mirror libraries for glass, Android?

Tags: android, google-mirror-api, google-glass

Do the Java libraries used in examples for Glass work with Android?

Do I just pull them over from the project to use them or is there some other way to import them?

Note: I'll be investigating this myself, but I'm at a hackathon so if I can find the answer faster that'd be great.

Comment: Got TimelineItem recognized using google-api-services-mirror-v1-rev20-1.16.0-rc.jar.  Have yet to test with it.

Now to find out how to get MirrorClient recognized...  I suppose I could copy ALL libraries from the other project...

Comment: Found more of what I was looking for here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/

Answer (score 1):

Although you could probably coerce the libraries to work under Android, you probably don't really want to in most scenarios. The Mirror API is meant to be used in a server environment to communicate with Google's servers which will then communicate with your Glass.